# Idiomatic population of an array as long as a property's value

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, idioms

I have a dice-rolling bot that spits out results via `var roll = new Roll('4#2d20+3')`. That constructor makes objects with properties parsed out of the string argument, which resembles this:

```
aRoll = {
  text: '4#2d20+3',
  times: 4,
  dice: 2,
  sides: 20,
  modifier: 3,
  roll: function() {...}
}
```

The `roll()` method should use the object's properties to generate an array of results. This is an exercise to learn what's new in JavaScript, so I'm curious how best to accomplish this.

Old, procedural way:

```
this.roll = function() {
  var total = 0;

  for (var i=0; i < this.dice; i++) {
    total += Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 1;
  }

  return total;
}
```

My attempt at new `Array` functional iteration:

```
this.roll = () => Array(this.dice).fill(0).reduce(state => {
  result + Math.floor(Math.random() * state.sides) + 1;
}, this);
```

This sorta works, but `Array(x).fill(0).reduce(...` is an ugly hack, and passing `this` in as `state` seems like a sign I'm doing the wrong thing.

Is there an `Array` method I should use instead? Or is the `for` loop still the cleanest way to accomplish this?

Comment: I kind of like the original method :)

Comment: I concur. A loop clearly expresses the semantics (add something n times). Functional style is usually fine, too, but here it requires you creating an unnecessary temporary array which deviates the reader's attention from *what* you want to achieve to *how* (via array) you want to achieve it.

Comment: instead of Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 1, you could use Math.ceil(Math.random() * this.sides)

Comment: @Brian I could, but in the rare event that `Math.random()` returns `0`, that would backfire.

Comment: Alternatively, write a function to draw from a binomial distribution (or use a library) and get rid of your loop via this abstraction by mathematical modelling. You might also want to ask this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I wouldn't  create an array at all - a simple loop can handle it with just O(1) memory while array creates O(n) space not to mention the overall repetitive iteration calls from the JS async chains.

Comment: Unless you're rolling the dice thousands of times per second I wouldn't worry about performance with numbers these small.  Instead of using Array(x).fill(0) you could use the Spread operator `[...Array(2)].reduce((t, d) => t = t + Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 1, 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out how this “should” be done.

The **first issue** is straightforward: [*do not use arrow functions as methods*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Arrow_functions_used_as_methods):

> An arrow function does not create its own `this` context, so `this` has its original meaning from the enclosing context.

`this` is the whole point of object-orientation, so breaking it is a bad idea. Passing `this` as `map()`’s second argument was indeed a code smell.

The **second issue**: instead of abusing `reduce()`’s initial value parameter with `this` to fake a `context` object, use a closure:

```
function roll(sides) {
  return (total) => {
    total + Math.floor(Math.random() * sides) + 1;
  };
}

someArray.map(roll(this.sides));
```

When you pass callbacks as arguments, but need to dynamically give them data that callers don’t provide, closures are the classic solution.

As for the **third issue**, populating an array the size of an object property, in order to call a function that many times…

There is no built-in boilerplate way. :•) @georg kindly provided a clean [implementation of a `times()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42867589/2522637) that reminds me of Ruby’s `Number.times()`, if you’re interested.

Answer (score 2):

One way to repeat a function n times is

```
Array.from(Array(n), fn)
```

To make all of this more readable, you could define, for example

```
let times = (n, fn) => Array.from(Array(n), fn);
let rand = n => Math.floor(Math.random() * n) + 1;
let sum = a => a.reduce((x, y) => x + y);
```

and then

```
roll = function() {
    return sum(
        times(this.dice,
            rand.bind(0, this.sides)));
}
```

Comment: Would you prefer `Array.from(Array(n), ...)` over `Array.from({length: n}, ...)`?

Comment: This is pretty rad, but I think I'm more interested in "standard library" ways; trying to get a feel for what idiomatic vanilla JS is like now.

Comment: @Tigt: well, `Array.from` is standard ES6

Comment: @le_m: I'd prefer `[1..n]` to be honest, unfortunately, JS committee is busy adding bells and whistles to the language instead of fixing its actual problems